# Using files with python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a txt file within my python code but I am unable to do so.
The problem asks to print the words which do not have a specific set of characters from the file.

```
def give():
    fin=open('words2.txt')
    line=fin.readline()
    for line in fin:
        word=line.strip()
        print word
def enter(forbid):
    words=give()
    for letter in words:
        if letter in forbid:
            return False
        else:
            print words
```

This code does not give a output at all

Comment: Are you sure you have indented your code correctly in your post?

Comment: You should correct the indentation and tell exactly what does not work. Does it print anything? Does it raise an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

def give():
    result = []
    with open('words2.txt', mode='rt') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            result += line.split()
    return result

def enter(forbid):
    words = give()
    for w in words:
        if all([letter not in forbid for letter in w]):
            print w


enter("bcdfghjklmst")
```

using this lorem ipsum (i.e. content from `words2.txt`):

> Eum dicta nihil iste quo minima repudiandae possimus. Provident nam
>   explicabo ut accusantium odit voluptatibus. Animi dolor sit deserunt
>   quisquam perspiciatis aut et voluptas. Repellat quo accusamus sint.
>
> Tempore vero iste rerum. Harum aut rerum qui rerum quis dolores
>   perspiciatis. Quas sed necessitatibus et rerum eum culpa. Autem
>   delectus aut sunt ab officiis sit non voluptatum. Id sequi voluptas
>   qui quo officia officiis placeat voluptatem.
>
> Nemo ipsa illo amet deleniti. Praesentium voluptatum voluptate
>   mollitia quod voluptates beatae. Doloremque molestias nostrum iste
>   possimus veritatis repellendus et dolor. Quidem sit iusto autem et id
>   dicta ut.
>
> Ad earum incidunt officia ea. Et quidem molestiae et facere. Culpa
>   harum veniam illum. Culpa quod porro in et eos adipisci. Sint
>   accusantium est qui inventore minima perferendis. Autem quidem omnis
>   et quia error enim nam.
>
> Distinctio velit ut facere animi delectus. Et deleniti expedita earum
>   nesciunt voluptas ea. In asperiores a nobis occaecati quam qui
>   repellendus molestiae. Excepturi distinctio consequatur commodi est
>   velit sit. Sit soluta a adipisci aut. Eos voluptatibus enim corrupti.

output (all word not containing any letter from "bcdfghjklmst"):

```
$ ./test_script2.py
quo
quo
vero
qui
non
qui
quo
ea.
porro
in
qui
quia
error
ea.
In
a
qui
a
```

Explanation:

- `give()` collects the words in a single list and returns them all
- inside `give()`, a `with` statement is used to ensure the file is properly handled (closed at the end...)
- `for w in words` browses all the words from the list
- `[letter not in forbid for letter in w]` is a [comprehension list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that contains booleans only. For each letter of the current examined word (i.e. `w`), it will put `True` if the letter does not belong to `forbid`. `all()` is `True` only if all the booleans from the list are `True`, so only if all letters of `w` do not belong to `forbid`
- the last part could be shortened

like this:

```
def enter(forbid):
    for w in give():
        if all([letter not in forbid for letter in w]):
            print w
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the indentation is wrong, also give() does not return anything so words is assigned a NoneType.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Actually the reason why `give()` does not return anything in the original code is not because of the wrong indentation (that should trigger a syntax error) but because `give()` has no `return` statement

Comment: @zezollo I tried to work that out. But unfortunately, it doesn't. I am trying to extract those words from the txt file that do not have those specific letters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a value in give() function..

```
def give():
    fin=open('words2.txt', 'r')
    line=fin.readlines()
    words = []
    for line in fin:
        word=line.split(" ")
        for i in word:
            print i
            words.append(i)
    return words
def enter(forbid):
    words=give()
    for letter in words:
        if letter in forbid:
            return False
        else:
            print words
            return True
```

Comment: this still dont print anything

Comment: still doesnt, maybe its python 3 im using

Comment: @SumanKalyan this won't work as intended because you will only return the first word. You should "collect" all the words in any iterator, then return it completely

Comment: @Cid-EL the `print` statements show this is python2 code

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, but could not work anything out, so I took a program i wrote some time ago, as far as i can see, you open the file on the wrong way, here is my code:

```
fo = open('your_file_name.txt','rt')
for line in fo:
    print(line)

fo.close()
```

as you can see you did not add the 'rt' wich stands for reading and text mode, hope this helped.

Thanks